# Can changing TypeScript compilerOptions->lib conflict with NPM Packages or Dependencies

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a question about the compilerOptions->lib property in `tsconfig.json`.

Situation is I'm working on a Firebase Cloud Functions project written in TypeScript and I need the method `Array.prototype.includes()`. But I was unable to build because includes() was not supported, a quick Google search showed I only had to change lib from ES6 to ES2016 which changes the version of Ecmascript.

My question is. Does changing the lib property do anything besides giving me newer/more functionality?

I'm worried if it somehow might conflict with Firebase Cloud Functions or the NodeJS version I'm using or NPM packages/dependencies.

Comment: Worth noting if you're building for browser deployment changing to `es2016` isn't going to make the `includes` method magically work in your target browsers that don't support it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the `lib` flag doesn't change the output of the Typescript compiler, the `target` flag does that.

`lib` simply includes the typings of the library versions you specify in the compilation process, so that compiler won't complain. (These typings could be found under node_modules\typescript\lib)

If your target runtime doesn't support the functions you use (includes() in this case), its your responsibility to provide it using a polyfill. Typescript doesn't actually include the library for you in the compiled output.

Comment: I have read a little bit about "target" and it confuses me a little bit that it does change the code to comply with the target with "var, let, const", but to my understanding it does not include a polyfill for "includes()".

Comment: You have to make the distinction between language and library features. " let, const" are language features. "includes()" is a library feature. Your runtime may support certain language features but library features may be absent.

Comment: TypeScript under no circumstance includes polyfills (To clarify, polyfills are for library features). It's our responsibility to include these.